# Where can I find the wireless driver for BCM4311 for OpenIndiana 148?

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi

I know that OpenIndiana 148 doesn't have the network driver (BCM4311) for the laptop.  I wonder if anyone out there can help, or point the way to me where I can get the driver?

Answer (score 2):

There are Broadcom wireless drivers for Solaris. The OpenSolaris Wiki used to have information regarding the use of a NDIS wrapper for Windows drivers, but, Oracle in their great wisdom appears to have removed any mention of it.

Sorry, but, OpenSolaris and it's struggling relative is in a pretty bad shape these days. You should seriously consider switching to a different OS.

Alternatively, use Oracle Solaris and pay for an expensive support contract, maybe they have a driver.